# Fibonacci Sequence Exercise

Tags: induction, fibonacci-numbers

I need some help checking the following solution.

The Fib sequence is defined by $a_1 = 1, a_2 = 1$ and for all $n\geq 2$, $a_{n+1} = a_n + a_{n-1}$. Thus, the sequence begins:

1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55,...

Prove that for all $n\geq 1$, $a_n <\left(\frac{5}{3}\right)^n$.

So far I have:

by induction

$a_{n+1} = \left(\frac{5}{3}\right)^n+1 = a_n+a_{n-1} < \frac{5}{3}\cdot\left(\frac{5}{3}\right)^n $ from the definition and factoring.

$\frac{5}{3}\cdot\left(\frac{5}{3}\right)^n  > a_n+a_{n-1} $

$\frac{5}{3}\cdot\left(\frac{5}{3}\right)^n  > a_n\cdot \frac{5}{3}$ from above

$a_n\cdot \frac{5}{3} > a_n + a_{n-1}$

This is where I get stuck, is this a complete solution? Or is there further computation needed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We need  [Strong induction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Complete_induction) here

Let   $a_n<\left(\frac53\right)^n$  for integer $1\le n\le m$

$\implies \displaystyle a_{m+1}=a_m+a_{m-1}<\left(\frac53\right)^m+\left(\frac53\right)^{m-1}=\left(\frac53\right)^{m-1}\left(\frac53+1\right)$

which will be $<\left(\frac53\right)^{m+1}$ if $\displaystyle \left(\frac53+1\right)<\left(\frac53\right)^2\iff 8\cdot3^2<3\cdot5^2$